# Valid OPENQUERY fails in BCP dynamic script

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp, openquery

Trying to execute SQL through OPENQUERY statement to linked MySQL server as a test

Interestingly the following openquery statement works:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([MYSQL], 'SELECT REPLACE(description,''/'','''') as description2, length(description) as DescriptionLength, length(example) as ExampleLength FROM `mysql`.`help_topic` ORDER BY `name`')
```

However, when added as part of the BCP output statement:

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)
select @sql = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([MYSQL], ''SELECT REPLACE(description,''/'','''') as description2, length(description) as DescriptionLength, length(example) as ExampleLength FROM `mysql`.`help_topic` ORDER BY `name`'')" queryout "C:\TEST_MySQL\NEW_TOO.txt" -c -t"\"~\"" -r"\"\n\"" -T -S'+ @@servername
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

It no longer works!

> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '/'.
> SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Unable to resolve column level collations
> BCP copy out failed

That same BCP statement above works fine when the   REPLACE(description,''/'','''') as description2  section is replaced with * on the inner select…!

Anybody have any ideas why this is occurring?

Comment: You didn't quote the openquery sql correctly, you need another set of '' inside the replace call, because the query is wrapped inside of another string, or perhaps use double quotes for string if that's allowed in mysql.

Comment: Thanks for trying siggemannen but that is not the answer, I tried already with 6 & 8 also, if add another 2 it adds another error line stating [Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'.], if add another 4 simply back to the same error

Comment: Well, try again. I'm pretty sure it should be `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([MYSQL], ''SELECT REPLACE(description,''''/'''','''''''') as description2, length(description) as DescriptionLength, length(example) as ExampleLength FROM sometable ORDER BY name'')` but i don't have mysql readily available

Comment: Well done siggemannen!  You are absolutely correct, I am so glad you wrote out the code as it should be to enable me to overcome my blindness to the fact that I forgot about doubling up on the 1st set of marks containing the slash, so hat off to you & thank you!